# Matlab Linear Regression

Tags: matlab

I have 4 data sets, and I need to perform linear regression on them. I keep getting errors in the matrices I've entered.

Here's what I tried to do: I entered the four different data sets as matrices and created a for loop that would go through each set of data and perform the same calculations on each one.

Not sure if my for loop will work - I have very very basic matlab knowledge and so any help would be appreciated!!

```
x{1} = [1; 2; 3];
y{1} = [2; 3; 4];

% Assume the following matrices are similar to the ones above 

x{2} = [...];
y{2} = [...];

x{3} = [...];
y{3} = [...];

x{4} = [...];
y{4} = [...];


for i = 1:1:4

z = [ones(size(x(i))) x(i)];
a = z\y(i); % Line with error

St = sum((y(i)-mean(y(i))).^2);
Sr = sum((y(i)-(10^(a(1))*x(i).^a(2))).^2);
r2 = 1-Sr/St;
syx = sqrt(Sr/(length(x(i))-length(a)));

end
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that. But I still get an error in line 1

Comment: Sardar Usama, I'm not sure what that means/how to correct that. And High Performance Mark every time I run my code it stops at line 1 because of an error

Comment: Use `{}` indexing with `x` and `y`. `x(1)` is a scalar (a single number), not an array. `x{1}` can be anything, including an array.

Comment: Okay thank you, I corrected that but now the line a =z\y(i) has an error

Comment: Not sure how to simplify my code further but I tried

Comment: You have to replace **all** `y(...)` with `y{...}`, not just on the first few lines of code.

Comment: omg thank you that worked!!

Answer (score -1):

this is as suggested in the comments a matter of {} istead of (). Try:

```
z = [ones(size(x{i})) x{i}];
a = z\y{i};
```